# Arch Linux Not Working After I Change Display Manager To Lightdm

Tags: arch-linux, boot, lightdm

So I thought about switching to LightDM. I switched by doing

```
sudo systemctl disable sddm
sudo systemctl enable lightdm
```

Then I restarted arch linux and everything ran fine. But then I thought about getting a better looking display manager. So I uncommented the line in /ect/lightdm/lightdm.conf that says this:

```
...-session=...slick...
```

I can't remember exactly what was there. Now, I think that I didn't install that theme, because when I booted up arch linux, it says "cannot boot light display manager" or something like that. However, I can't figure out how to access the terminal. If I get the terminal, I can just change back the display manager or re-comment that line. How do I fix this? All I need to do is access the terminal and then I'm good to go, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: you need to edit `grub` and force system to boot to `rescue` mode or `emergency` mode and then mount root. this link can be useful https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Add `3` as your boot argument. Revert the changes. Reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system boots at all, you can always switch to a terminal and back to the DE with the Ctrl + Alt + F1, ... + F2, etc. key combo. There is no need to edit grub.

From a terminal you can edit the file you need then reboot.